# Extract specific records from a text file

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract specific records from the below text file. and I have to pick only specific records from the file.

Input File:

```
Record 0:
[record
  InputData [record
              RecType            "001"
              MyData            [record
                                RefTable "001" 
                                RefTableDesc    "Metadata "]
              MyAdd             NULL
              MyType            NULL
              MyRole            NULL]]
Record 1:
[record
  InputData [record
              RecType            "001"
              MyData            [record
                                RefTable "002" 
                                RefTableDesc    "Metadata "]
              MyAdd             NULL
              MyType            NULL
              MyRole            NULL]]

Record 2:
[record
  InputData [record
              RecType            "002"
              MyData            NULL
              MAdd             [record
                                   MY_ADD_CD       "00 "
                                   MY_ADD_SHORT_NM "MY Specific"
                                   MY_ADD_NM       "My Specific Addendum"
                                   MY_ADD_TYPE_CD  "01 "]
              MyType           NULL
              MyRole           NULL]]
Record 3:
[record
  InputData [record
              RecType            "002"
              MyData            NULL
              MAdd             [record
                                   MY_ADD_CD       "001"
                                   MY_ADD_SHORT_NM "MY Specific"
                                   MY_ADD_NM       "My Specific Addendum"
                                   MY_ADD_TYPE_CD  "01 "]
              MyType           NULL
              MyRole           NULL]]
```

Here is my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = shift || 'dump.txt';
my $word1 = shift || 'RecType';
my $word2 = shift || 'RefTable';
my $word3 = shift || 'RefTableDesc';
my $word4 = shift || 'MY_ADD_CD';
my $word5 = shift || 'MY_ADD_SHORT_NM';
my $word6 = shift || 'MY_ADD_NM';
my $word7 = shift || 'MY_ADD_TYPE_CD';

my @output;
open my $fh, '<', $fn or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";

while (<$fh>) {
        if ($. = /\b$word1\b/i) {
   push @output, split;
}
elsif ($. = /\b$word2\b/i ){
        push @output, split;
}
elsif ($. = /\b$word3\b/i ){
        push @output, split;
}
elsif ($. = /\b$word4\b/i) {
   push @output, split;
}
elsif ($. = /\b$word5\b/i ){
        push @output, split;
}
elsif ($. = /\b$word6\b/i ){
        push @output, split;
}
elsif ($. = /\b$word7\b/i ){
        push @output, split;
    print "@output\n";
    @output = ();
         }
}
close ($fh);
```

Here is the output which I am getting:

```
RecType "001" RefTable "001" RefTableDesc "Metadata " RecType "001" RefTable "002" RefTableDesc "Metadata " RecType "002" MY_ADD_CD "00 " MY_ADD_SHORT_NM "MY Specific" MY_ADD_NM "My Specific Addendum " MY_ADD_TYPE_CD "01 "
RecType "002" MY_ADD_CD "001" MY_ADD_SHORT_NM "MY Specific" MY_ADD_NM "My Specific Addendum " MY_ADD_TYPE_CD "01 "
```

Desired Output:

```
"001"  "001"  "Metadata " 
"001"  "002"  "Metadata " 
"002"  "00 "  "MY Specific"  "My Specific Addendum "  "01 "
"002"  "001"  "MY Specific"  "My Specific Addendum "  "01 "
```

Please suggest if there is any way to achive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a parser for those records which you can use to generate your output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = shift || 'dump.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $fn or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";

sub read_record { 
    my %record;
    my $end;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        (my $key, my $value,$end) = /\s*(\w+)\s+([^\]]*)(\]*)\s*$/;
        $end = length($end);
        if ( $value && $value =~ /\[record/ ) { 
            ($record{$key}, $end) = read_record();
        } elsif ( $value =~ /"(.*?)\s*"/ ) { 
            $record{$key} = $1;
        } elsif ( $value =~ /NULL/ ) {
            $record{$key} = undef;
        }
        last if $end;
    }
    return wantarray ? (\%record, --$end) : \%record;
}

my @records;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( /^Record (\d+):/ ) { 
        <$fh>; # toss the [record line
        $records[$1] = read_record();
    } 
}
close ($fh);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@records;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'InputData' => {
                             'MyAdd' => undef,
                             'MyType' => undef,
                             'MyRole' => undef,
                             'MyData' => {
                                           'RefTable' => '001',
                                           'RefTableDesc' => 'Metadata'
                                         },
                             'RecType' => '001'
                           }
          },
          {
            'InputData' => {
                             'MyData' => {
                                           'RefTable' => '002',
                                           'RefTableDesc' => 'Metadata'
                                         },
                             'RecType' => '001',
                             'MyAdd' => undef,
                             'MyType' => undef,
                             'MyRole' => undef
                           }
          },
          {
            'InputData' => {
                             'RecType' => '002',
                             'MyData' => undef,
                             'MyRole' => undef,
                             'MyType' => undef,
                             'MAdd' => {
                                         'MY_ADD_SHORT_NM' => 'MY Specific',
                                         'MY_ADD_TYPE_CD' => '01',
                                         'MY_ADD_CD' => '00',
                                         'MY_ADD_NM' => 'My Specific Addendum'
                                       }
                           }
          },
          {
            'InputData' => {
                             'MyData' => undef,
                             'RecType' => '002',
                             'MyRole' => undef,
                             'MyType' => undef,
                             'MAdd' => {
                                         'MY_ADD_NM' => 'My Specific Addendum',
                                         'MY_ADD_CD' => '001',
                                         'MY_ADD_TYPE_CD' => '01',
                                         'MY_ADD_SHORT_NM' => 'MY Specific'
                                       }
                           }
          }
        ];
```

But, if you just want your output and don't care about the records, the problem is far simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = shift || 'dump.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $fn or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print "$1 " if /("[^"]*")/;
    print "\n" if /\]\]/;
}

close ($fh);
```

Output:

```
"001" "001" "Metadata " 
"001" "002" "Metadata " 
"002" "00 " "MY Specific" "My Specific Addendum" "01 " 
"002" "001" "MY Specific" "My Specific Addendum" "01 "
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, boy.  `$.` is the current line number in the file.  Try this:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = shift || 'dump.txt';

open my $INFILE, '<', $fname 
    or die "Could not open file '$fname': $!";

while (my $line  = <$INFILE>) {
    say $.;
}

--output:--
1
2
3
...
...
45
46
```

From perlvar:

> You can adjust the counter by assigning to $. , but this will not
>   actually move the seek pointer.

What does that mean? Exactly?  Let's try it out:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = shift || 'dump.txt';

open my $INFILE, '<', $fname 
    or die "Could not open file '$fname': $!";

while (my $line  = <$INFILE>) {
    say $.;

    if ($. == 1) {
        $. = 10;
    }
}

--output:--
1
11
12
13
...
...
54
55
```

So, assigning to `$.` just changes the number that `$.` counts from.

In your code, you have a series of if/elsif statements like this:

```
    if ($. = /\b$word1\b/i) {
```

In `scalar context`, which is the context you create when you assign something to a scalar variable (i.e. a variable whose name begins with the sigil $), the `match operator` returns `0` if there's no match, or `1` if there is a match.

As a result, your if-statement sometimes assigns 0 to `$.`:

```
if ($. = 0) {
```

And other times your if-statement assigns 1 to `$.`:

```
if ($. = 1) {
```

That's all well and good, except you never use the value of `$.` after assigning to it, and therefore it is a useless assignment.  You just repeatedly assign new values to `$.` as the if/else branches execute.

Because your code does not depend on the value you assign to `$.`, you should remove it:

```
if (/\b$word1\b/i)
```

Next, an if conditional is considered a `boolean context`, i.e. a true/false context, and a boolean context is a scalar context(you just have to memorize that).  So now you know: an if conditional is a scalar context.  And as was stated above, the match operator in scalar context returns 0 when there is a match, or 1 if there's no match. As a result, the if-statement:

```
if (/\b$word1\b/i)
```

...is equivalent to:

```
if( 0 )  #when there is no match
```

...or:

```
if ( 1 ) #when there is a match
```

Finally, in a boolean context 0 is considered false, and 1 is considered true.  So, when there is a match, the if/else block executes; and if there's no match, the if/else block is skipped.

What in the world possessed you to assign values to `$.`?  perl has lots of global variables, how did you pick `$.`?  And, I'm wondering why you didn't write:

```
my $x;

if ($x = /\b$word1\b/i)
```

Assigning to $x is just as useless as assigning to `$.`, but at least you aren't mucking up perl's global variables.

The next problem is: your code dumps all the data into an array, which means you have no idea where the data from one match ends and the data from another match begins.